# Laravel 4 debugging not working

Tags: debugging, laravel, laravel-4

It's extremely frustrating that I have 'debug' => true in the app config but all Laravel is showing is "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." For the love of coding, does somebody know how to get debugging to work?

Comment: What environment are you in? Did you copy the `app/config/app.php` to another configuration environment and not change `debug` to `true` there?

Comment: Additionally, all errors will show in your error logs. Always check the error logs :D (`app/storage/logs` and/or the ones setup per your web server - perhaps in `/var/logs/`).

Comment: i am also getting this problem

Answer (score 17):

I have faced the same problem. Laravel was showing only "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." but this line and not showing the actual error. Then I have checked the app/config/app.php file and changed `"debug" => false` to `"debug" => true` and it worked perfectly.

You said that you have also done it and still not working. I suggest you to run a `composer update` command for your project and then try again.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4 on windows and the config is actually located at project_root/app/config/app.php. In fresh project, debug configuration is located at the top of the app.php file and should be changed the way that @BlackJack suggested

Answer (score 2):

To be sure your app is in development mode, edit `bootstrap/start.php`, in the `detectEnvironment` function simply put your machine name. On linux use `hostname` terminal commande to determine your machine name.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('homestead', 'Jeanphi'),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually debugging is working fine for me with L4.0.7 when i set `'debug' => true` in app/config/app.php
That switch tells Laravel to turn on Whoops and to bypass the 'compiled.php' file. When it is disabled, Whoops will not show. A normal server error page is served instead.

Were you expecting something else?

EDIT: maybe you are referring to "debugging" as the old profiler bar that were in L3 (Anbu). In that case I suggest you install [this package](https://github.com/juy/profiler)

Answer (score 0):

Check you haven't renamed your app/config folder as fideloper suggests in the comment.

For example you might have renamed it to prevent overwriting the default config settings when copying your site somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For all it's worth, I was getting this error now after deployment because I didn't create these folders:

```
/app/storage/cache
/app/storage/logs
/app/storage/meta
/app/storage/sessions
/app/storage/views
```

Answer (score 0):

Some changes need an apache restart to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I came across problem recently, after separating out `debug` and a few other config options into a separate (dev.php) config file.

The in-hindsight obvious, by-logic obscure solution: **Don't move `debug` out of config/app.php**

Answer (score 0):

Had that same problem altought my app was in debug mode.
In my case I was deploying on server,and to make that work 
you must take care of **detectEnvironment** variable.

It is located in ***bootstrap/start.php***

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

       'local' => array('your_server_name'),

));
```

as it's instructed in the docs :

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem several times and I have two possibilities.

- the folder storage doesn't have the right permissions, you should use chmod 755 or chmod 777
- the public/index.php has none permission or a 777

These two options has occurred to me before, maybe there are some more.

Answer (score 0):

i got same problem with that...
first, laravel run well on windows using apache..
then while i'm using ubuntu and nginx, it shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

no error in php log and nothing found on laravel log..

so i tried modify path folder permission to 0777

> sudo chmod -R 0777 {put your folder application folder here}

it works

Answer (score 0):

well you need to clear configuration cache and regenerate it each time you change config files

run 'php artisan config:cache' in console and your good to go