# Can not view the rows of the authors table (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Hello and thanks for the help! I'm new to laravel and i'm trying to learn it through a tutorial that i found in youtube! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lceNwQf-ufY

Everything has been worked correctly until now!
I'm trying to make a list of all the rows of my table `authors`

My Controller **authors.php**

```
<?php

    class Authors extends BaseController{
    public function get_index(){
    return View::make('authors.index')
    ->with('title', 'Authors Title')
    ->with('authors', Author::all());
      }
    }
```

My Model **author.php**

```
<?php
class Author extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'authors';

}
```

My View **index.blade.php**

```
@extends('authors.layout')
@section('content')
   <h2>Authors Page</h2>
   <h3>Welcome to the authors page</h3>
   <ul>
@foreach($authors as $author)
   <li>{{ $author->name }}</li>
@endforeach
   </ul>
@stop
```

And my layout **layout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    </head>
        <body>
        @yield('content')
        </body>
</html>
```

**Routes.php**

```
<?php
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    });
    Route::get('users', function()
    {
        return View::make('users');
    });
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

Comment: did you have any data in your authors table?

Comment: Probably outdated tutorial. Change `get_index` to `getIndex` for a start. Otherwise show the errors you have. Take a look at www.laracasts.com for valuable info.

Comment: @worldask Yes the table has 5 rows! Jarek I have changed the"get_index" but nothing happened. Still the same, i get this "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: Does your environment work well?

Comment: Where is your routes file? Do you have this `index.blade.php` and `layout.blade.php` inside `authors` directory in `view` folder?

Comment: No, I just get all the time this message  "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: Did you turn debug on? Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787342/laravel-4-debugging-not-working), maybe you can find sth.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have updated my post, you can see the routes file. The blade files are in the correct folder!

Comment: @worldask I have turned it right now! Thanks, It will help me for the future problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in your `routes.php`

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

to

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'Authors@get_index'));
```

Using `Authors@get_index` the first part is the name of controller (in your case it's `Authors` and the second part is the name of method - in your case it's `get_index` and not `index`.